# JMeter test action not pausing

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter test executing a series of actions that I'd like to pause between.

It's currently set up like this:

```
Thread Group
+---Transaction controller
    +---Sampler executing request
    +---Test Action
        +---Uniform Random Timer
    +---Sampler executing request
    +---Test Action
        +---Uniform Random Timer

(etc.)
```

The test actions don't seem to cause any pauses. I have the test actions themselves set to pause the current thread for 0 milliseconds, and the timers to 60 seconds constant pause + up to 30 seconds random pause.

The actual result of running this is that it hops directly from sampler to sampler without pausing at all. What am I missing?

(ETA: This is JMeter 2.13, if that matters.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you confirm that you use time in **milliseconds** in the Uniform Random Timers, to wit:

   - Random Delay Maximum: 30000
   - Constant Delay Offset: 60000

   As if you have 30 and 60 correspondingly - the delay happens, but you are not detect it visually. Check "Sampler Start" times in [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to see start times.
2. Can you double check Transaction Controller configuration? By default timers, pre and post-processors execution time is not being included into report so the delay might happen but you just don't see it. You can include timers duration by checking "Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample" box
3. And finally you can also remove Test Action samplers as they're not required. If you put timers as children of "Sampler execute request" the timers will be executed before the requests. See [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) guide for more detailed information on timers use cases.